# Cross Over From ...To

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs, figurative-language

A question about "*cross over*" [here](http://www.mercurynews.com/my-town/ci_26486972/teachers-and-social-media-trekking-treacherous-terrain):

> "We all joke about the ways that we could maliciously behave in our jobs," Goldman said. "That's gallows humor. Going online gets problematic. With (Hodges) it was not just a joke, it was a running theme. At some point it ***crosses over*** from being a joke to a warning sign."

According to dictionaries, "*cross over*" could either a musician changing from one genre to another, or a person switching allegiance from one political party to another.
But neither definition applies to the usage in the example.  Could it be an error?

Answer (score 3):

This is an ordinary use.

If an expression like this doesn't show up in as a distinct idiom in your dictionaries it is usually not because it is an error but because it is not an idiom: its meaning can be deduced from its components. *Cross over from A to B* means to move from a position on one side of the literal or figurative line dividing A from B to a position on the other side, in the process passing over and across the line. You may cross over from the United States to Canada, from childhood to adulthood, from college to the workforce.

In fact that is the meaning in your two examples noted in your dictionaries: a musician who crosses over from rock to rap or from pop to country crosses the vague line which separates the genres, and a politician who crosses over from the Democrats to the Republicans crosses a similarly vague ideological line. (In the UK it is, to be sure, a literal crossing as well, from the Government to the Opposition benches in Parliament.)

Comment: So, the example usage (a comment crossing over from a joke to a warning sign) is wrong?

Comment: @meatie As I have just explained, it is ordinary usage. There's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Then, can I write:  "He crossed over from a high school student to a college student"?

Comment: You can; though we would more likely say "He crossed over from high school to college".

Comment: Yet, this more general definition could not be found in any dictionaries?

Comment: As I said, you should not expect dictionaries to include collocations whose meanings can be deduced from their  components -- only those whose meanings cannot. Would you expect to find "go up" or "be found" in a dictionary?

Comment: Do you think a definition for "cross over" that fits my example exists in some big-shot dictionary?

Comment: @meatie I doubt it. I'm going to guess you found this not under *cross over*, verb, but *crossover*, adjective, whose uses are not intuitively obvious: they lack the specific *from...to...* context which is ordinarily provided with the verb.

Comment: How come so many words/phrases in use are not found in dictionaries?  Could it be a sign of language defects?

Comment: @meatie Did you understand my first comment? There is no need to put a phrase like *cross over* into a dictionary because it does not mean something different from *cross* + *over*. It is not an ['idiom'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiom), just two words used together with their ordinary meanings. If you know what *cross* means and what *over* means you know what *cross over [something]* means.

Comment: But "cross", according to many online dictionaries, does not mean "change".

Comment: @meatie But to *cross over* from one place or state to another always means to change position, whether the position is literal or figurative. Figurative, non-literal uses are not different meanings but the same meaning in different contexts. You cannot expect a dictionary to list every figurative context a word might be used in: that would in effect require the lexicographer to record every sentence ever written and to predict every sentence that will ever be written.

Comment: @StoneyB - I think the O.P. [understood your first comment just fine](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/is-it-okay-for-users-to-delete-questions-and-re-ask-them-verbatim/1186#1186).